# Manipulating variable values using values from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset, `df`, where columns consist of various chemicals and rows consist of samples identified by their `id` and the concentration of each chemical.

I need to correct the chemical concentrations using a unique value for each chemical, which are found in another dataset, `df2`.

Here's a minimal `df1` dataset:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="id,chem1,chem2,chem3,chemA,chemB
1,0.5,1,5,4,3
2,1.5,0.5,2,3,4
3,1,1,2.5,7,1
4,2,5,3,1,7
5,3,4,2.3,0.7,2.3",
header = TRUE,
sep=",")
```

and here is a `df2` example:

```
df2 <- read.table(text="chem,value
chem1,1.7
chem2,2.3
chem3,4.1
chemA,5.2
chemB,2.7",
header = TRUE,
sep = ",")
```

What I need to do is to divide all observations of `chem1` in `df1` by the value provided for `chem1` in `df2`, repeated for each chemical. In reality, chemical names are not sequential, and there's roughly 30 chemicals.

Previously I would have done this using Excel and index/match but I'm looking to make my methods more reproducible, hence fighting my way through with R. I mostly do data manipulation with dplyr, so if there's a tidyverse solution out there, that would be great!

Thankful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the 'chem' column from 'df2' to subset the 'df1', divide by the 'value' column of 'df2' replicated to make the lengths same and update the columns of 'df1' by assigning the results back

```
df1[as.character(df2$chem)] <- df1[as.character(df2$chem)]/df2$value[col(df1[-1])]
```

Comment: in OP chem1, id=1 = 0.5 and in df2 example value of 1.7 is 0.5/1.7=0.29 ...  I ran your solution on the example data and get 0.17 ?

Comment: @Soren Not sure how you got it.  I am getting `(df1[as.character(df2$chem)]/df2$value[col(df1[-1])])$chem1[1]
#[1] 0.2941176`

Comment: Yup, checks out fine, not sure what I did first time!  (probably leftover env variable). 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using reshape2 package, the data frame can be changed to long format to merge with the df2 as follows.  (Note that the example df introduce some whitespace that are filtered in this solution)

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- read.table(text="id,chem1,chem2,chem3,chemA,chemB
1,0.5,1,5,4,3
                  2,1.5,0.5,2,3,4
                  3,1,1,2.5,7,1
                  4,2,5,3,1,7
                  5,3,4,2.3,0.7,2.3",
                  header = TRUE,
                  sep=",",stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- read.table(text="chem,value
chem1,1.7
                  chem2,2.3
                  chem3,4.1
                  chemA,5.2
                  chemB,2.7",
                  header = TRUE,
                  sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = F)

df2$chem <- gsub("\\s+","",df2$chem) #example introduces whitespaces in the names
df1A <- melt(df1,id.vars=c("id"),variable.name="chem")

combined <- merge(x=df1A,y=df2,by="chem",all.x=T)
combined$div <- combined$value.x/combined$value.y
head(combined)

   chem id value.x value.y       div
1 chem1  1     0.5     1.7 0.2941176
2 chem1  2     1.5     1.7 0.8823529
3 chem1  3     1.0     1.7 0.5882353
4 chem1  4     2.0     1.7 1.1764706
5 chem1  5     3.0     1.7 1.7647059
6 chem2  1     1.0     2.3 0.4347826
```

or in wide format:

```
> dcast(combined[,c("id","chem","div")],id ~ chem,value.var="div")
  id     chem1     chem2     chem3     chemA     chemB
1  1 0.2941176 0.4347826 1.2195122 0.7692308 1.1111111
2  2 0.8823529 0.2173913 0.4878049 0.5769231 1.4814815
3  3 0.5882353 0.4347826 0.6097561 1.3461538 0.3703704
4  4 1.1764706 2.1739130 0.7317073 0.1923077 2.5925926
5  5 1.7647059 1.7391304 0.5609756 0.1346154 0.8518519
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution.

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
    # convert the data from wide to long to make the next step easier
    gather(key = chem, value = value, -id) %>%
    # do your math, using 'match' to map values from df2 to rows in df3
    mutate(value = value/df2$value[match(df3$chem, df2$chem)]) %>%
    # return the data to wide format if that's how you prefer to store it
    spread(chem, value)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when piped. The full pipe returns an error on the length of 'value'. Maybe because the mutate calls for the df3 tibble that is created at the end. The method does work in the non-pipe format, though: 
df3 <- gather(df1, key = chem, value = value, -id)
df3 <- mutate(df3, value = value/df2$value[match(df3$chem, df2$chem)])
df3 <- spread(df3, chem, value)

Comment: Sorry, it's that I accidentally left `df3` in the call to spread in the last line.